Relation between the spectrum of a ring and the spectrum of its reduced quotient ring
I'm trying to understand the solution to this exercise:

Let $R$ be a ring. Show that $\text{Spec}(R)$ is irreducible if and only if the nilradical $\sqrt{( 0)}$ is prime.

Here we define the set $V(I)$ for an ideal $I\subseteq R$ as $V(I) = \{P\in\text{Spec}(R) \space |\space I\subseteq P \}$ i.e., $V(I)$ is the set of prime ideals in $R$ containing $I$. Furthermore, the $V(I)$ are the closed subsets of $\text{Spec}(R)$ regarding the Zariski topology.
The solution to this first recalls the fact that $\displaystyle \sqrt{I} = \bigcap_{P \in V(I)}{P}$ and later states that $\text{Spec}(R)\simeq \text{Spec}(R/\sqrt{0})$ and thus the problem can be reduced to reduced rings, i.e.,

If $S$ is a reduced ring, then $\text{Spec}(S)$ is irreducible iff $S$ is a domain.

I understand the rest of the solution, but I'm still stuck on the validity of the statement $\text{Spec}(R)\simeq \text{Spec}(R/\sqrt{0})$. Why is this true?

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

When you say $Spec(R)$ is irreducible, I'm assuming you mean in the topological sense (i.e hyperconnected). Is that correct?

Yes, that's how it's meant @XStanton

$\sqrt{0}$ is contained in all prime ideals, so there's a correspondence between the prime ideals of $R$ and $R/{0}$.

If $\phi:A\to B$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, then the map \begin{align}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}
\phi^*:\Spec B&\to\Spec A \\
\mathfrak p&\mapsto\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak p) \, ,
\end{align}
is a homeomorphism of $\Spec B$ onto $V(\ker\phi)$. This contains your theorem as a special case.
To prove the more general theorem, we note that since $\phi$ is surjective, $B$ is isomorphic to the quotient of $A$ by $\ker\phi$, and hence there is a one-to-one correspondence
$$
\{\text{prime ideals of $B$}\}\longleftrightarrow\{\text{prime ideals of $A$ including $\ker\phi$}\} \, ,
$$
i.e. a correspondence between $\Spec B$ and $V(\ker\phi)$. The forward map in this correspondence is simply the corestriction of the map $\phi^*$, hence continuous. The backward map $\psi:V(\ker\phi)\to\Spec B$, $\mathfrak p\mapsto\phi(\mathfrak p)$ is continuous because if $f\in A$, then
\begin{align}
\psi^{-1}(V(\phi(f)))&=\{\mathfrak p\in\Spec A\mid \text{$\mathfrak p\supseteq\ker\phi$ and  $\phi(f)\in\phi(\mathfrak p)$}\} \\[4pt]
&= V(\ker\phi)\cap V(f) \, ,
\end{align}
which is closed in $V(\ker\phi)$. This suffices to establish the continuity of $\psi$, since the complements of the sets $V(\phi(f))$ form a basis of $\Spec B$.

Here is an alternative way of proving that if $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}\phi:A\to B$ is a surjective homomorphism, then the induced map $\phi^*:\Spec B\to\Spec A$ restricts to a homeomorphism $f:\Spec B \to V(\ker\varphi)$. It is based on Lemma 1.7 (p. 28) of Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves.
Presumably, you already know that $f$ is continuous, and we know from elementary algebra that $f$ is a bijection. It thus suffices to show that $f$ is a closed map. Suppose $J$ is an ideal of $B$. It is routine to verify that $f(V(J))\subseteq V(\phi^{-1}(J))$ (this much is true regardless of whether $\phi$ is surjective). For the reverse inclusion, note that if $\mathfrak p\in\Spec A$ and $\mathfrak p\supseteq\phi^{-1}(J)$, then $\phi(\mathfrak p)\supseteq\phi(\phi^{-1}(J))=J$. Hence, $\mathfrak p\in f(V(J))$.
